# What happens to 'Similar apps' section if I change the category on Play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app on Play Store. Its been there for around 2 years. I recently changed the category of the app. Within 3 hours, the category was changed throughout Play Store.
But the 'Similar apps' section on my app's Play Store page remains unchanged? Even after changing the category of my app, it still shows the old category apps in the 'Similar apps' section. It shall show apps of new category, right?
Does Google even change this section or it takes time to change? It's been more than 24 hours now. Please help.

What happens to 'Similar apps' section if I change the category on Play store?

Comment: I think you have to mail google play store team for this.

Comment: I don't think there is a contact form where they accept these questions from developers. Send me link if you find one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can take Google at least 4 days to update the 'Similar apps' section. Be patient and wait.